# not hasCass selector in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to iterate over all thead's on the page except the ones that have a parent table that *contains* the class 'foo'.

The code below gives me an error because :hasClass is not a valid expression, but it helps illustrate what I'm trying to achieve (I hope).

```
$("table:not(:hasClass(foo)) thead").each(function() {
    // Sample code
});
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but

```
$("table:not(.foo) thead").each(function() {
    // Sample code
});
```

seems not to work (It only omits the tables with class "foo" and not "foo bar"?)

Am I going about this way too difficult?

EDIT:
answer given

Comment: What do you mean by "a parent table that *contains* the class 'foo'"? The table has the class? Or it has some element somewhere inside it with the class?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking, nor what you want to achieve. Are you saying you want to exclude tables that have a `thead.foo` element?

Comment: I want to exclude theads that have a parent table which contains the class 'foo'

Comment: In which case what's the issue with `:not(.foo)`?

Comment: hmm, that works, but not on my page, sorry for the question, the problem lies somewhere else.
Thanks for the answers

Comment: *"Correct me if I'm wrong but `$("table:not(.foo) thead")...` seems not to work (It only omits the tables with class "foo" and not "foo bar"?)"* It will skip both tables with `class="foo"` and with `class="foo bar"`.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: You can delete the question until you've looking further into what's going on...

Comment: I could edit with the answer?
I had to use `$("table:not(.foo) > thead")...`
because there were parent tables that did not have the class .foo so it still selected those theads.
Should I delete the question?

Comment: Your question doesn't give enough to go on to support your answer because it's missing certain key information, like the HTML you're working with. If you do post an answer, you should post it as an answer rather than an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code:

```
<table class="bar">
    <table class="foo">
        <thead>
        </thead>
    </table>
</table>
```

but

```
$(table:not(.foo) thead)
```

selects the thead's which have *any* parent without the class 'foo', a selection which the table with class 'bar' satisfies.

The solution is to apply the :not()-selector only the *direct parents* of the thead's I wish to filter out through:

```
$(table:not(.foo) > thead)
```

Thanks for the help in the comments.